# Have a dot follow a path selected path

Tags: javascript, canvas

What i am trying to do is to click a position on a canvas and have a dot follow a path directly to the position i have selected.

this is my code so far.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
//
var clickedChords = {
x: 0,
y: 0
};
var player = { 
x: 100, 
y: 100
};

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getChords, false);        

function getChords(e) {

  clickedChords.x = e.pageX - rect.left;
  clickedChords.y = e.pageY - rect.top; 

}

function draw() { 
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 

 ctx.fillStyle= 'black';
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(clickedChords.x,clickedChords.y,3,0,360);
 ctx.arc(player.x,player.y,3,0,360);   
 ctx.fill();

 if(player.x > clickedChords.x && player.x !== clickedChords.x){     
     player.x -= 1;  
 }  
 if(player.x < clickedChords.x && player.x !== clickedChords.x){ 
     player.x += 1;     
 }
 if(player.y < clickedChords.y && player.y !== clickedChords.y){  
     player.y += 1;
 } 
 if(player.y > clickedChords.y && player.y !== clickedChords.y){  
     player.y -= 1;
 }

 }setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Right now all i have managed to do was to get the dot to follow a 45 degree angle then hit and follow the x or y value of my clicked position. I have tried to use the slope formula but i am clueless on how to implement it into my code.

Thank you for helping as i am truly stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interpolation for this:

```
var t = 0,                 // will be in range [0.0, 1.0]
    oldPlayerX,            // need these for interpolation
    oldPlayerY;

function getChords(e) {
    clickedChords.x = e.pageX - rect.left;
    clickedChords.y = e.pageY - rect.top; 

    oldPlayerX = player.x, // copy these as we need them as-is
    oldPlayerY = player.y;

    draw();
}

function draw() { 

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 

    ctx.fillStyle= 'black';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(clickedChords.x,clickedChords.y,3,0,360);
    ctx.arc(player.x,player.y,3,0,360);   
    ctx.fill();

    if (t <= 1) {
        player.x = oldPlayerX + (clickedChords.x - oldPlayerX) * t;
        player.y = oldPlayerY + (clickedChords.y - oldPlayerY) * t;
        t += 0.05;                   // determines speed
        requestAnimationFrame(draw); // use this instead of setInterval
    }        
}
```

The interpolation itself happens on these lines:

```
player.x = oldPlayerX + (clickedChords.x - oldPlayerX) * t;
player.y = oldPlayerY + (clickedChords.y - oldPlayerY) * t;
```

It basically do a difference between new and old position. `t` will determine how much of that difference is added to the original position, ie. if t=0 then nothing, if t=1 then full difference is added to old position which obviously equals the new position. Anything in between (for `t`) will add a percentage of that allowing you to animate the point.

`requestAnimationFrame` allow you to sync the animation to monitor refresh. A setInterval value of 10 ms is way to short for the browser to handle (minimum is 16.7ms for a screen refresh @ 60 Hz).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer, although there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek isn't two lines of codes simple enough? :) The rest is for integration in his code. And it's faster than trigonometry as atan2/cos/sin are relative expensive methods compared to +/*. You could cache those values though but ending up with more code. Just sayin'..

Answer (score 0):

We can just use some basic trigonometry:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(clickedChords.y - player.y, clickedChords.x - player.x);  
player.x += Math.cos(angle);
player.y += Math.sin(angle);
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/w2vCc/1/